# Combining D&D 4th ed. Player's Handbook 1, 2 and 3

Tags: dnd-4e

The gaming group I'm in is returning to D&D after not having played it for quite a few years. During character creation the following question came up:

Can feats, powers etc. from all three PHB books be mixed and matched as one sees fit? Or are, say, feats from PHB2 inseparable from rules that are in PHB2 but not in PHB1?

I only own PHB1 right now, and I'm using the DDI Character Builder, which doesn't seem to differentiate between the PHB (1) and PHB2, PHB3, Divine Power, Martial Power feats, powers etc.

Comment: The player handbooks can all be mixed and matched with no problem, however, if you use the old monster manuals, look up the new erratad stats for them. Monsters have been redesigned and are more fun now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes.** The designers intended all 4th edition material to be compatible.

Comment: This includes the Essentials line.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will enjoy it like we do. What i want to ad on the comments above is that there is an option in the character builder to in- or exclude books. For example if you want to use PHB 1,2 and 3 and not all the other material because you don't own the books (yet) you can deselect other material to keep it simple and clear.

Comment: Thanks, shak. Could you expand a bit on how you select/deselect source material in the Character Builder?

Comment: Ah, ok - I'm using the online one, and as far as I can tell, you can't limit the source books.

Comment: i use the old offline one but probably it will be almost the same. Go to manage and then campain settings. From there i deselect all exept for example in my campain phb1, 2 and 3 and the adventure vault 1 and 2 (this ads the magic items in the shop of those 2 books). Next is save campain. From now if you make a new char after you started go to manage etc.. take your campain and then when you go back to build options you will see that all the other races etc from other content are not an option anny longer. I hope i made it a bit clear (i mostly get a bit messy when explaning a lott)

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.